# FBML: Toggle visibility of Facebook "Like" button

Tags: facebook, fbml

Is there a way to accomplish these 2 simple things:

- Hide the "Like" button when the user
  opted to "Like" it.
- On page load, check if the user "Like"s the page. If TRUE, hide the
  "Like" button. If FALSE, show it.

Comment: Have you manage to solve this?

Comment: Nope. I just left it as it was. Although I figured this can be achieved using jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second thing you want to do is easy to do:

```
     FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove', function(href, widget) {
     // run some jQuery to hide a div that holds the like button

     });
```

the first has been breaking my balls for the last 48 hours, but I'm there now.

**(Edit: I'm very new to this myself, so take in mind my ignorance and limited understanding)**
What you need to know though is that a facebook user must give you permission for you to know whether he or she is fan-of/likes your page. This means you must create a FB application and link it to your page. Upon loading/liking the user will be asked for permission to share his basic information. For a simple hide of a 'like button' this seems excesive. If you're interested though, I can tell you more about this.